# Question about integrating my python Django-Dash-Plotly app to a sub-domain in SquareSpace

Tags: django, plotly-dash

I currently have a python app deployed using Django, which uses Dash-plotly as a critical aspect. All of my copy/content has to be done through source code, which works for me, but is not convenient for everyone. I have a friend that wants to help me with the copy/content website. So due to circumstances: I want to create a SquareSpace for the website, and then use a sub-domain to connect the python app.

Would it make sense to keep my app deployed via Django (trimming down all unnecessary code)? And then just connect my app to the sub-domain? The last thing I want is for things to feel slowed down, I have my doubts that Django might be overkill for this specific case.

How viable would this turn of events be in terms of development?